# Laravel Route Action

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Between the two ways of writing route action, which is the fastest and most efficient?

```
Route::get('halo', [Api\V1\Client\HomeController::class, 'index']);

// or

Route::get('halo', "App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\Client\HomeController@index");
```

In this case, I have almost 500 routers, does the writing method of the two routers affect?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This route: `Route::get('halo', [Api\V1\Client\HomeController::class, 'index']);` is Laravel 8 upwards version and the other is Laravel < 8.n. So the question would be which Laravel version you will use.

To the performance issue. Laravel cache the routes. It means it doesnt matter which style you will use.

Maybe must be the question which laravel version is faster.

Comment: I'm curious because the first route directly executes the class, the second is the conversion process from string to class::function(etc), does it still not affect program execution which makes it slower?

Comment: @Sidik As already written! Laravel stores all routes! so it doesn't matter how complex the mapping is.

Comment: @Sidik actually they both work the same way - you are not passing a class instance, since writing HomeController::class just returns the string representation of the class. So in both situations it does the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

How you write a route has no effect on how fast the code will run. Whichever way you write, the basic function of the code remains the same.